# what is the proper way to print multiple string on a single line in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import os
from urllib import *

userInputedUrl=input("Enter URL:")
directory_list=open("directory.txt",'r') 

OK="200 OK"
Error="404 Error"

for item in directory_list:
    requestParameters=userInputedUrl+"/"+item
    final=requestParameters.rstrip('\n')
    response=requests.get(final)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("\n")
        print("Found " + item + OK,end='')
    else:
        print("\n")
        print("Not Found " + item + Error,end='')
```

I am making the web application directory bruteforcer this program takes the website name with user and get directories names from directory.txt and send request to the website by appending directory name one by one.
this program is printing status code on next line but i want output of 'Found directory 200 OK' or 'Not found directory 404 Error'.

Comment: Can you show us the exact output you see?

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to do so would be:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Found {} {}".format(item, OK))
    else:
        print("Not Found {} {}".format(item, Not_OK))
```

Also I wouldn't call the second string Error since it's a keyword that's already defined. I removed the `print("\n")` since the print function already add it at the end of the line, keep it if you want an empty line between each.

Comment: Found programmes
 200 OK                                       still i am getting this :-)

Answer (score 0):

`print` takes many arguments and it will concatenate them as follows:

```
print("Found", item, OK)
```

Note that you should not put space after "Found", `print` will automatically put spaces between the arguments.

Also, in python 3.6+ you can use the following:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Found {item} {OK}")
else:
    print(f"Not found {item} {Error}")
```

And as Antoine said, *Error* is not a good variable here,